# Statement of mathematical approach

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I have a statement that says:
>
> A teacher A does a job in 6 hours, while a teacher B runs it in the
>   twice as long as the teacher A. In how many hours would they work
>   together?

So, I did the trivial thing:

$w^{-1} = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3}$

$w^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}$

$w = 2$

Then, they take $2$ hours to do the work together. I have solved several exercises in this way and they were fine, but why not here? , since the answer should be $ 4 $

Comment: Twice as long means 12 hours, not 3. You'll find that 1/12 + 1/6 = 1/4.

Comment: Right, I was multiplying the inverse $2 * 6^{-1}$, thanks

Comment: $2 \times 6^{-1} \ne (2 \times 6)^{-1}$. How would you have approached it differently if the problem had just simply said "teacher B runs it in 12 hours"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teacher A completes one unit of work in $6$ hours, so has a rate of completion of $\frac{1 \text{ unit of work}}{6 \text{ hours}}$.  Teacher B completes one unit of work in twice $6$ hours, which is $12$ hours, so has a rate of completion of $\frac{1 \text{ unit of work}}{12 \text{ hours}}$.  Together they have a rate of completion of
\begin{align*}
 & \frac{1 \text{ unit of work}}{6 \text{ hours}} + \frac{1 \text{ unit of work}}{12 \text{ hours}}  \\
=& \frac{2 \text{ units of work}}{12 \text{ hours}} + \frac{1 \text{ unit of work}}{12 \text{ hours}}  \\
=& \frac{3 \text{ units of work}}{12 \text{ hours}}    \\
=& \frac{1 \text{ unit of work}}{4 \text{ hours}}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
Therefore, we expect the pair of teachers to complete the work in $4$ hours.